# How to display list of random numbers generated without braces n drracket scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to remove braces from 1st column of my output. 1st element is displaying list of random numbers.

I tried using (display x out)

Output:-

> (0.6120010214616108)  0.5925590107832954
>
> (0.8356229511111914)  0.38111428504698647
>
> (0.4528839015867216)  0.8884464805374491
>
> (0.43983176152338427) 0.9231042042839553
>
> (0.4003430698698756)  1.042755057187469

Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, in the point where you're printing an element of the random list:

```
 (display (car x) out)
```

In other words: instead of printing `x`, print the first element of `x` and it should look fine.